# Line after text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

So far I've done this:

```css
h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 48px;
  margin-right: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>html</h2>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.7em;
  width: 48px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/100% 4px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2>html</h2>
```

If you want the red to be rounded you can try like this:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:50px;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) center right/ 30px 4px no-repeat;
}

h2:before,
h2:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:5px;
  height: 0.7em;
  width: 4px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:35%;
}
h2:after {
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h2>html</h2>
```

**Update**

if you want it under the text you can rely on only background:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 8px 8px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red)   bottom right/4px 15px,
    linear-gradient(red,red)   bottom left /4px 15px, 
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 calc(100% - 5px)/100% 4px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2>html</h2>
```

and with radius like this:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 8px 8px;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 calc(100% - 5px)/100% 4px no-repeat;
}

h2:before,
h2:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  height: 0.7em;
  width: 4px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:35%;
}
h2:after {
  left: 0;
  right:auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>html</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! and what if a want it to put just under the text? what to do?

Comment: @ElleWilliamssss any one you want ;) I made different ways

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I am programmed to do so ;)

Comment: @John you removed the accepted answer because I closed you question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54362619/8620333) as duplicate? :) ... I am not against this, you can also downvote my answer but you should know that closing a question as duplicate isn't bad and there is nothing against *you*. I actually provided you with the answers that you need, simply take the time to read them. In case none of them are helpful, edit your question to show how they aren't helpful (don't simply add `I have looked to already answered questions but nothing seems to work with my probilem`)